# AS3 Movieclip Spawner - on startDrag movieclip appears on stage

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, drag-and-drop, movieclip, appendchild

The basic idea. In my drag on drop project, on the stage, I have a pile of jewels (a static photo/movieclip) where the the player can drag little jewels from, and move them into the central window. I want to have so that the jewel movie clip - lets call it **jewel_mc** that can spawn an infinite amount of child clips which can them be moved around the stage. This where I need some help, where to go from here. - I'm an AS3 novice.

Tailoring the function - what I need : So when the player clicks to "startdrag" from the pile of jewels_mc a small gem appears on the mouse cursor, when the player releases, a gem is drop in that last position. The player can do this as many times as they like, so long as they start drag from the stack jewel stack.

you are tweezering a load of jewels onto a plate!

I would appreciate any help, thanks. 
from another draggable object

```
 jewel_mc.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, pickuplittlejewel_mc);
 littlejewel_mc.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, droplittlejewel_mc);

 function pickuplittlejewel_mc(event:MouseEvent):void {
 event.target.startDrag(true);
 }
 function droplittlejewel_mc(event:MouseEvent):void {
 event.target.stopDrag();
 }
```

I've guessed this script above, I'm not sure how close I am to my results.
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I dont know if I understand you very well, but I try to explain you:

Imagine that you have an Jewel MovieClip on your library, then with this code you can create infinite Jewels and next drag and drop them:

```
import flash.display.Sprite;
import flash.events.MouseEvent;

this.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, createJewel);

//---Global variable
var _jewel:Sprite;

//---Create jewel
function createJewel(evt:MouseEvent){

    _jewel = new Jewel();

    _jewel.x = evt.stageX;
    _jewel.y = evt.stageY;

    addChild(_jewel);

    _jewel.startDrag(false);
    _jewel.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, dragJewel);
    stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, dropJewel);

}

//---Jewel start drag
function dragJewel(evt:MouseEvent){

    //---Avoid the event propagate to the Stage
    evt.stopPropagation();

    _jewel = evt.currentTarget as Sprite;

    _jewel.startDrag(false);

    stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, dropJewel);

}

//---Drop jewel
function dropJewel(evt:MouseEvent){

    stage.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, dropJewel);

    _jewel.stopDrag();

}
```

Here you have a flash with the exmaple:

[example fla](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0Bw9pbLM_BascYVk5aVk1eGNVWXc/edit?usp=sharing)